# Ionic Firestore CollectionReference.doc() error

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding some array in firestore in all docs but its showing error

```
core.js:6014 ERROR FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an array
```

I have array i need to save it in all docs. So first ill fetch all document ids and then save array in all docs but showing error here is my code.

```
getAllDocs(seen){
  this.angularFirestore.collection("HomeGroup").snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes=>{
      return changes.map(a=>{
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id}
      });
    }
        )).subscribe(items=>{
          console.log(items);
          this.ids = items;

         this.angularFirestore.collection('HomeGroup').doc(this.ids).add(seen);
      })

     }
```

it think problems is in ids ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`items` is an array, when you store it inside `this.ids` then `this.ids` will become an array. You need to iterate inside the array and retrieve the `id`:

```
items.forEach((ids) => {
    console.log(ids);
    this.idValue = ids.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an array to the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method, you need to pass a string, as indicated by the error. One approach would be to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows. `Promise.all()` allows to execute many Promises in parallel, and wait until all of them are resolved.

```
//....
.subscribe(items=>{
       const promises = [];

       items.forEach(item => {          
            promises.push(this.angularFirestore.collection('HomeGroup').doc(item.id).set(seen));
       });
       return Promise.all(promises);
})
```

Also, note that `add()` is not a method of a `DocumentReference`. You probably want to call [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) or [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update). If you do `set(seen)` or `update(seen)`, you should take care that `seen` is an object of type [`DocumentData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.html#documentdata) or [`UpdateData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.html#updatedata).

Comment: @UmaizKhan Hello, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?